# Отрезать часть большого архивированного текстового файла

Tags: файлы

Есть текстовый файл 35Гб в tar архиве 5Гб. Нужно от начала отрезать ПРИМЕРНО 0,5 Гб текста и сохранить как отдельный файл. Как это сделать на домашнем компьютере или каком-нибудь сетевом ресурсе типа Google Colab?

Comment: Как это? содержимое в одном файле весит больше чем весь tar?

Comment: Вероятно подразумвается что-то вроде tar.gz? В голых tar-архиах нет сжатия.

Comment: @andreymal а вдруг `.tar.xz` или `tar.bz`?

Comment: @DiD поэтому я защитился словом «вроде» )

Comment: Для .tar.gz — `tar zxf archive.tar.gz --to-stdout textfileinarchive.txt | head --bytes=512M >outfile.txt`

Comment: @andreymal, да, конечно, спасибо! Поправил.